# Reference request: $d X_t = b(X_t) d t + f (p_t(X_t)) d W_t$ where $p_t$ is the p.d.f. of $X_t$

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $b:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R^d$ and $\sigma:\mathbb R^d \to \mathcal M_{ d\times q} (\mathbb R)$ be Lipschitz. Let $(W_t, t\ge 0)$ be the standard $q$-dimensional Brownian motion. Then
$$
d X_t = b(X_t) d t + \sigma (X_t) d W_t \quad \text{a.s.},
$$
has a unique strong solution. Now let $f:\mathbb R_{\ge 0} \to \mathcal M_{ d\times q} (\mathbb R)$ be "nice" enough. I'm interested in the existence of the solution of the SDE
$$
d X_t = b(X_t) d t + f (p_t(X_t)) d W_t \quad \text{a.s.},
$$
where $p_t$ is the probability density function of $X_t$.

I would like to ask if there are references related in this direction. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Comment: how about starting from considering the corresponding Fokker-Plank equation for the density eg. https://users.aalto.fi/~ssarkka/course_s2014/handout3.pdf? To at least see if we get a well-posed pde. So now in the FP one of the coefficients will involve the density again.

Comment: one good reference for that is "Existence and uniqueness of martingale solutions for SDEs with rough or degenerate coefficients"

Comment: The corresponding FP nonlinear parabolic pde is
$$\partial_{t}p(x,t)=-\partial_{x}(b(x)p(x,t))+\frac{1}{2}\partial_{xx}\left((f (p(x,t)))^{2}p(x,t))\right).$$
and so for weak regularity on f  we can only study this in distributional sense.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thank you so much for your suggestion! I will check it out.